# Conversion of objects position in pixel to geographical coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, raster, r-raster, coordinate-systems

I have some objects positions (`left_x,top_y,width,height`) in pixels in a *jpg image (`sample_7958`) with 98 width x 81 height:

```
im.name<-rep("sample_7958",3)
obj<-c(1,2,3)
left_x<-c(2,56,61)
top_y<-c(-0,23,37)
width<-c(9,15,32)
height<-c(8,14,23)
total_im_width<-c(98,98,98)
total_im_height<-c(81,81,81)
im.ds<-data.frame(cbind(im.name,obj,left_x,top_y,width,height,total_im_width,total_im_height))

im.ds
      im.name obj left_x top_y width height total_width total_height
1 sample_7958   1      2     0     9      8          98           81
2 sample_7958   2     56    23    15     14          98           81
3 sample_7958   3     61    37    32     23          98           81
```

I know that in the original image in *tiff the center of the image has the `X,Y(803958,7674280)` coordinates and `0.05686330017443669976,-0.05686329721392673064` pixel size, then I'd like to find any way to convert and create new columns in `im.ds` with X,Y geographic coordinates of borders (`Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax`) for each object (1 to 3). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think this is just straightforward arithmetic:

```r
x_centre     <- 803958
y_centre     <- 7674280
image_height <- 81
image_width  <- 98
pixel        <- 0.05686330017443669976

y0 <- y_centre + pixel * (image_height) / 2
x0 <- x_centre - pixel * (image_width) / 2

im.ds$Xmin <- left_x * pixel + x0
im.ds$Xmax <- (left_x + width) * pixel + x0
im.ds$Ymax <- y0 - top_y * pixel
im.ds$Ymin <- y0 - (top_y + height) * pixel

im.ds
#>       im.name obj left_x top_y width height total_im_width total_im_height
#> 1 sample_7958   1      2     0     9      8             98              81
#> 2 sample_7958   2     56    23    15     14             98              81
#> 3 sample_7958   3     61    37    32     23             98              81
#>       Xmin     Xmax    Ymax    Ymin
#> 1 803955.3 803955.8 7674282 7674282
#> 2 803958.4 803959.3 7674281 7674280
#> 3 803958.7 803960.5 7674280 7674279
```

Perhaps plotting the results will help with the visualization:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(im.ds, aes(Xmin, Ymin)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Xmax, yend = Ymin)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = Xmax, xend = Xmax, yend = Ymax)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = Xmax, xend = Xmin, y = Ymax, yend = Ymax)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Xmin, y = Ymax, yend = Ymin)) + 
  labs(x = "X", y = "Y") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(x0, x0 + image_width * pixel),
                  ylim = c(y0 - pixel * image_height, y0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>